# Steam No Man's Sky on Mac?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have downloaded Steam on my Mac, will I be able to buy No Man's Sky?

I am reading that it is only available for the PC, if so I am gutted

Comment: There is currently no official release date for Mac.

Comment: As a fellow Mac owner, it's very easy to *buy* non-Mac games on Steam (and support will scold you a bit when you ask for the refund). I imagine your question is really whether you can *play* it.

Answer (score 12):

Buy? Yes. Even if the Steam client won't let you buy the game because your OS is not supported, you can always use your browser to buy the game.

However, if you want to *play* the game, that is a different issue. According to [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/275850/) and [GoG](https://www.gog.com/game/no_mans_sky), these are the minimum system requirements for *No Man's Sky*:

> MINIMUM:
>   OS: Windows 7/8.1/10 (64-bit versions)
>   Processor: Intel Core i3
>   Memory: 8 GB RAM
>   Graphics: nVidia GTX 480, AMD Radeon 7870
>   Storage: 10 GB available space

As you can see, OSX is not supported. So no, you can't play the game on a Mac (yet).

However, assuming your Mac is relatively modern, you can install Windows on it (using [Boot Camp](https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/)). Therefore you won't need a new PC to play the game.

Comment: The OP *might* be able to play it, if his Mac has a graphics card of the required sophistication.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, macOS probably wouldn't handle the game too well.  Unless you have a Mac Pro, you will probably be left running the game (if it is ported or if you run it in Bootcamp or Wine*) on low graphics settings.

I played it today with a 980ti graphics card and it was kind of choppy even with a 6-core i7-5820k at stock 3.3 Ghz.

I have no idea if it will run on Wine, it's just a possible solution for those who use Windows Apps on Mac.  If you have never heard of Wine, I suggest you stay away from this as it can be technical, especially since the developer stated that VCRedist 2010 is needed to run the game, managing software dependencies for the casual gamer is difficult in Wine.

Comment: Why wouldn't OS X handle it well? It's the same graphics as most windows machines, and my mac could definitely handle it.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ. Multiple reasons, ranging from driver support to the way the OS is built. From my experience, games have always required a more powerful Mac compared to Windows PCs. I can't say if it's because of OSX, or if it's because the games just aren't optimized for OSX though.

Comment: Well the fact that I have a 6 GB 980ti Sea Hawk (comparable with Titan X) and a 6 core i7-5820k and can run the game at 91 fps, while a friend of mine has a quad-core i7 (4th Gen) and graphics card comparable to most Mac computers and runs the game at 9 fps.  I have an iMac as well with a 680 MX that probably wouldn't handle the game.  As far as driver support, that isn't as much of an issue as they use close to the same drivers, I can agree with the statement that the games are not optimized for OS X though.

Comment: Most game engines are written in C and C++ which is not a problem when it comes to portability other than ensuring that the proper header libraries are included when moving to a different platform.  The problem with porting a game comes from the additional frameworks such as the .NET framework for Windows or the Obj-C foundation.h and Swift code needed for Mac.  Then comes the lower level problems of how fast the code runs, which may not be suitable for NMS.  You also have to account for the bitness of each architecture, 32-bit/64-bit, which is only a problem when it comes to 32-bit Linux.

Comment: @BobR. Luckily Microsoft has started open-sourcing the .NET framework

Comment: @Nolonar A lot of game developers get tricked into using DirectX, a Windows-specific clone of OpenGL that Microsoft specifically designed to make it hard to port later on. If you were tricked into using DirectX and you want to bring your game to Mac (or Linux), you first have to rewrite the game in OpenGL. Developers often make optimization mistakes while rewriting the game, causing lower FPS. This created the myth that Mac and Linux are less optimized for games. They are actually _more_ optimized for games than Windows; properly written code almost always performs better on Mac and Linux.

Comment: @JopV. It really doesn't help that users can't install Intel-, Nvidia-, or ATI-written graphics drivers on Mac.  They're forced to use the drivers written by Apple, which have [really outdated OpenGL support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823).  Now, with Metal, Apple has even less reason to properly support OpenGL.  Linux has far less market share, so they don't get as much graphics card driver love.  Driver support is a vicious cycle.  (Also, Direct3D is the counterpart to OpenGL, not DirectX (which refers to the whole suite.))

Answer (score -2):

**Possible** solution is to run a Windows Virtual Machine on your MAC to play the game or wait for MAC release.

Comment: No, this isn't really the only solution.

Comment: Then what is another solution?

Comment: @TrassVasston, did you read the other answers?

Answer (score -2):

One other solution is to try the game under wine.